# Can node.js handle a 1k sql record manipulations?

Tags: node.js

I’m considering node.js for a backend application. Node will run a Rest API (express) and front a Postgres dB. I might have to make queries returning 1k records and I would then need to do in memory filtering/data manipulation to return Json Responses to my API.

I might be facing at 10-100 TPS (transaction per second).

I know I can’t block the event loop, but I’m not able to wrap my mind over what is considered blocking in terms of CPU processing load.

Comment: are you referring to issues for threading?  https://levelup.gitconnected.com/handling-nodejs-c-p-u-extensive-task-aa559452eca8

Comment: @Earl Yes my fear is to commit to node and realize that my processing requirements are blocking the event loop.

Comment: We're currently using node to process 1k TPS with an azure sql. Key takeaways: 1) the sql server should do as much output processing as possible, and 2) stream the query results back to the node process instead of waiting for the entire batch of data to be returned from sql (when possible)

Comment: @jorgenkg I’m not sure I understand 2). Do you mind giving an example maybe ?

Comment: Node is pretty good at I/O indeed. But bad for expensive computation since its (by default) single threaded.

Comment: @TomTom the limitation isn’t the 10 TPS the limitation is the manipulation of 1k records in the callback.

Comment: @Kam What kind of manipulation is it?

Comment: @Klaycon I’m reading 1k records, then based on business logic I’m going to go through the records maybe filter, or edit some values and transform the records into a new json object that is returned back as a response to an api call

Comment: @Kam This is not nearly an amount of processing you need to be worried about for an API. For context, I run a bot that receives numerous thousands of messages per second that each trigger a postgres query that can return up to 3k rows, which are then iterated and string matching done on each one. Yes, it's not efficient, but my server still has plenty of resources - computers are blazingly fast these days.

Comment: @Kam The most you  might have to do is create worker processes to split the processing load between your CPU cores, something Node is perfectly capable of doing.